# Multiple router outlets with normal URL's

Tags: angular, angular-routing, router-outlet

I have Angular 6 app, and want to create multiple router-outlets inside one dashboard-page, but when i have named outlet (for example, outlet with name 'settings'), i got URL's looks like `/app/(settings:user-profile)`, what looks weird and not user-friendly. Can i have normal URL's (like `/app/user-profile/`, or `/app/settings/user-profile` at least)?

Comment: In second case, there is no way to specify routes to other outlets. So you might need to change app architecture. Sometimes things are ugly but beautiful

Comment: agree on change app architecture